# How do I add multiple source folders to a JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, build

I have a large JAR file from a library, the source code of which is scattered across multiple different folders, so I have to merge these folders manually and specify the single merged folder as the source.

Is there any way in Eclipse to link more than one source folder to a specific JAR? I am guessing not and various tricks I have tried do not seem to work, but if anyone knows of one that works, please post it.

Comment: 2013 and I still can't find this option in Eclipse Juno

Comment: Off-topic but I wonder if NetBeans or IntelliJ can do that or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these answers have mis-understood the question. The request was how to add multiple source folders for **library** jars used by a project - NOT to add multiple source folders for the project itself.

I don't beleive at this time there is a solution for that. There are a couple of bug reports on the Eclipse bug tracker asking for the feature, but for now, we are both stuck with consolidating the source folders manually

Answer (score 0):

If your source folders are all in the same parent folder,
add the parent folder instead.

All subfolders are scanned and attached.

Answer (score -1):

On your project, click `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder...` to add a new source folder.

Comment: I agree with amanda. Every source folder when exporting is packed to single jar, war. But you should declare it that is source folder and in settings where is output folder and which files to include.